# Passing parameter to RestSharp GET request

Tags: c#, service, drupal-7, restsharp

I'm trying to communicate with a Drupal site to access a particular node.  I'm using C# and RestSharp to gain access to the data.  I can get the following to work in FireFox RestClient:

> http://localhost/drupal/gpa/node?parameters[type]=product_activation

It returns the correct node type.  But, everything I've tried to code using RestSharp does not work.  I either get all node types, or, none at all.  The code I use:

```
restClient = new RestClient(“http://localhost/drupal/gpa/node”);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

request.Method = Method.GET;
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("X-CSRF-Token", csrftoken);
request.AddHeader("Cookie", sessid);
request.AddParameter("type", "product_activation", ParameterType.GetOrPost);

var response = restClient.Execute(request);
```

This results in every node being returned.  And, the response uri is:

> {http://localhost/drupal/gpa/node?type=product_activation}

Can anyone explain how to correct the passing of the parameter to access just the requested type?

Comment: Just guessing but have you tried `parameters[type]` instead of just `type` in `AddParameter`?

Comment: Yes.  When I code it that way, I get nothing returned.

Comment: What if you try `restClient = new RestClient("http://localhost/drupal/gpa/node?parameters[type]=product_activation");`?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that also.  It returns a null array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this.  Through some debug coding, I noticed that even when I pulled all of the nodes, the type I was looking for was missing.  That pointed me to the Drupal system where I discovered that the node was not "published".  This meant that to the outside world, the node did not exist.  Hence, I could not retrieve it.  This code worked once I made the node "published":

```
restClient = new RestClient(RestGetNodes);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

request.Method = Method.GET;
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("X-CSRF-Token", csrftoken);
request.AddHeader("Cookie", sessid);
request.AddParameter("parameters[type]", "product_activation");
```